# What would be the cleanest way to test for a pessimistic version number constraint using PHP?

Tags: php, compare, version

I have the following version comparisons: `=, >, <, >=, <= and ~>`.

I can test for all except `~>` with the build in PHP version compare function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php)

What would be the best way to test for `~>` when I have an array of sorted version numbers as well as a version I want to compare against?

`~> 2.6 means anything higher than 2.6 and less than 3.0, so 2.7, 2.9 are ok
~> 2.6.1 mean anything higher than 2.6.1 but less than 2.7.0, so 2.6.5 is ok`

Lets say I have the following:

```
~> 1.0.3

array(
    '1.0',
    '1.0.1',
    '1.0.4',
    '1.0.8',
    '1.1.0',
    '1.2.0',
    '2.1.2',
);
```

I want to get back `1.0.8`

EDIT: I want the highest possible version number with the constraint `~> 1.0.3`

Comment: Should you not be returning 1.0.4 also?

Comment: Yes, sorry I have updated my question I am looking for the highest possible.

Comment: Have you taken a look at how [Composer](https://github.com/composer/composer) handles it?

Comment: I didn't know composer uses this kind of version locking. I will take a look, thanks!